# Initializing an array and doing forEach() on it in one statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

Every example of `forEach` I can find is written like:

```
const arr = ['A','B','C']

arr.forEach((letter)=>{
 //do stuff
})
```

Is it bad practice to do it this way instead?:

```
;['A','B','C'].forEach((letter)=>{
 //do stuff
})
```

It just seems unnecessary to name a variable for the array you'll be iterating over. Also, why is the semicolon needed in order for the latter example to work?

Comment: Sure, go ahead and do it inline if there's no use for the variable elsewhere

Comment: The semicolon isn't needed?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's an unusual style that puts semicolons before statements instead of after statements. Needed in cases like `foo() <newline> ;['A', 'B', 'C'].something`

Comment: @CertainPerformance indeed that makes sense. In isolation it seems unnecessary